# Differentiating Data Powershell

Tags: powershell

So we have a lot of data that comes in very sporadically,

examples:

```
> Col 1               col 2            col 3 
> 0123456             35 StreetName    2134  
> 22 Street Name      0123456          2121 
> 2121                0123456          32 street name
> 32 streetname 1212  01474412312      1212
```

In Power shell what would be the best to differentiate between these bits of data?

Trying to put the data in the correct col, so all addresses in 1, phone numbers in 2 and zip codes in 3.

the data comes in like,

```
$s = "0123456" (how would i know that this belongs in col 3)
$s = "35 street name" (how would i know that this belongs in col 1)
$s = "1212" (how would i know that this belongs in col 2)
$s = "32 Street Name 3212" (how would i know that this belongs in col 1)
$s = "0(3) 6363727" (how would i know that this belongs in col 3)
```

Comment: What would be the best...what?  Differentiate how?  It would be helpful if you explained what you're trying to do and how you've tried to do it.

Comment: just trying to put the data in the correct col,

so all addresses in 1, phone numbers in 2 and zip codes in 3

Comment: What do you know about the data and the formats? Will phone numbers ever be `1-800-ABCDE`, will they ever be `+1(0) 20 123 456 ext 3 ask for Deb.` ? Will the ZipCodes all be USA? Will the addresses all have text always? If you can't nail down the differences, you can't answer it. If you can only nail down the differences a bit you have to make up some rules of thumb to try and identify them. If you know exactly where they come from and what the limits are, maybe you can identify them exactly.

Comment: Yes exactly,
all the data comes in slightly different,
zip codes my be attached to the address string, contact numbers can contain special characters. is there a function that can read as ## LLL (# meaning number L meaning A-Z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regexp to test the incoming string:

```
switch -Regex ($string) {
    '^\d{1,4}$' {
    # 1-4 digits and nothing else
        $col = 'zip' # or 1 depending on your data format
    }
    '\d{6}' {
    # 6 digits anywhere inside
        $col = 'phone' # or 3 depending on your data format
    }
    default {
        $col = 'address' # or 2 depending on your data format
    }
}

$row[$col] = $string # or $row.$col = $string depending on your data format
```